# Enumerations within classes

Tags: c++

Lets say I have a class C which has an attribute state which can take values down, flat or up. Rather than representing the state variable as an integer we can use enumerations instead (which ofc basically are integers). For example,

```
class C{
public:
    enum state {down = -1, flat = 0, up = 1};
    C(state s = flat) : st(s) {}
private:
    state st;
};
```

The reason for putting the enum inside the public section of the class is so that other objects can use this enumeration list as well. They would have to call

```
C::up
```

to retrieve the value up. My question is: Is the a "best practice" for either placing enum declarations inside a class defintion, or outside it (e.g. directly above it)?
If the enumeration represent values/states which only has a meaning to that class then it feels intuitive to place it within the class definition.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an enum semantically only has sense in context of a class, then it is completely natural to hold it inside. If it has global meaning, it should be outside the class. In any case, the placement of the enum should reflect the semantics of the system under development.

Thus, I completely agree with your last sentences.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely don't want free floating enums - they should either be in a class or namespace. If the enum only has meaning in that specific class, then it is probably best practice to place it inside - I believe SFML has an example of this with its events (sf::Event has a member of type sf::Event::EventType, which can take values such as sf::Event::KeyPressed etc.).

Comment: I agree, at least placing it within a namespace (which essentially is what we accomplish by placing it inside the public section within a class definiition) feels best. Like you said, to avoid free floating enums.

Answer (score 0):

If you use C++11, you can use *strongly typed enums*. These are of the form:

```
enum class state
//     ^
{
    Down, Flat, Up
};
```

You would now access these using:

```
state::Down
state::Flat
state::Up
```

Note that this requires you to qualify/`using` the element, which is always good practice. However, not that these enums are *type safe* so cannot be arbitrarily used as integers (you probably shouldn't do this anyway).

Comment: Ah, that's actually quite nice.